# mysqli_connect and a bad host name - weird behavior

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am currently writing a program that allows the user to enter in the hostname, username, database, and  password on the front end.  In the back end I use mysqli_connect.  I noticed that if the user enters in an incorrect host name or a host that doesn't exist, I don't get an error but the program stalls and I have to restart apache.  I would like to avoid this, for the time being I am hard coding 'localhost' as host but I'd like to not do that. I've used a die statement at the end of mysqli_connect but it still stalls.

My question is this:  Is there a way to limit mysqls search for a host to 10 seconds or a short amount of time?  Or is there a good way to validate or check if the host exists before I use mysqli_connect?

Comment: You shouldn't (and probably can't) use `or die` with the `mysqli` constructor as it always returns an object. Instead use `if ($mysqli->connect_error)`

Comment: You can use [`mysqli::real_connect`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.real-connect.php) to set the connection timeout

Comment: depending on versions there should be a mysql "connect timeout" variable

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for the `MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` option.

Conveniently documented here:  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php

```
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
$mysqli->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 5);
$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```